# Prove claim using reductio ad absurdum

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, solution-verification

I was given a claim that is know to be true and must prove it using reductio ad absurdum (RAA).

The problem states:

> $\textbf{M}$ is the set of students in an academic program. $\textbf{A} \subset \textbf{M}$ are the students in the program who enrolled in class A. $\textbf{B} \subset \textbf{M}$ are the students  in the program who are happy. Both $\textbf{A}$ and $\textbf{B}$ are non-empty.
>
> The following proposition is known to be true:
>
> $a \in \textbf{B} \implies a \in \textbf{A}$
>
> Prove this proposition using RAA.

This is what I tried initially:

> Suppose $a \in \textbf{B}$ and $a \notin \textbf{A}$.
>
> From the known proposition, it follows that $a \in \textbf{A}$.
>
> $\therefore a \in (\textbf{A} \cap \textbf{M\\A}) = \emptyset$ for any $a \in \textbf{M}$.
>
> $\therefore \textbf{B} = \emptyset$, but $\textbf{B} \neq \emptyset$, so the proposition must be true.

Needless to say, I am not convinced by my own attempt. Moreover, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173967/proof-using-reductio-ad-absurdum-raa) says that to prove something using RAA you must contradict the entire proposition, not just its right hand side. So how can I prove this using RAA?

Comment: No, this is right. Remember that the statement P AND Q is false when at least one is false.

Comment: Oh, so by negating the implication I implicitly negate the entire proposition?

Comment: Yes. The negation of P AND Q is P AND (NOT Q).

Comment: Great. Thanks. Would you like to submit that as an answer?

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. What do you mean when you say the proposition is "known to be true"? Does that mean it's an assumption or does it mean it's a consequence of given properties of the sets $A$, $B$ and $M$? The latter is false: take $M = \{1, 2\}$, $A = \{1\}$ and $B = \{2\}$ to see why.  But if it's an assumption, then it doesn't need to be proved.

Comment: "Prove X is true, knowing that X is true.  Suppose X is false.  But X is known to be true, so that is a contradiction.  Therefore X is true.  Q.E.D."   This is valid, but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove $P \implies Q$, you can show that $P \ \& \ \sim Q$ is false. What you have done is correct - you've arrived at a contradiction!

Comment: That justifies the superficial structure of the OP's proof. It doesn't justify what the OP actually writes.